# My array list to .txt file program is giving me several errors

Tags: java, string, swing, arraylist, filewriter

I have an inventory application that sets a list of strings based on user input. Than it is supposed to export the strings to a .txt file.
I have never used FileWriter before, and am very much stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is all the relevant code:

The three lines near the end that have 'writer.' in them are giving me a `unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class mVentory extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form mVentory
     */
    public mVentory() {
        initComponents();

    }

    public class ProductInfo {

        String name;
        String des;
        String ID;
        String num;

        public ProductInfo(String name, String des, String ID, String num) {
            this.name = name;
            this.des = des;
            this.ID = ID;
            this.num = num;
        }
    }

    public static void Inventory() {

    }

    //creat Array
    ArrayList<String> Inventory = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void AddGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Add Item
        String Name, Description, Identification, Number, Item;

        Name = NameIn.getText();
        Description = DesIn.getText();
        Identification = IDIn.getText();
        Number = NumIn.getText();

        Item = "" + Name + "," + Description + "," + Identification + "," + Number + ".";

        Inventory.add(new String(Item));

        NameIn.setText("");
        DesIn.setText("");
        IDIn.setText("");
        NumIn.setText("");

    }

    private void ExportGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        FileWriter writer;
        writer = new FileWriter("Inventory.txt");
        for (String str : Inventory) {
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: For a specific answer, please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your chosen approach.

Comment: You have to use `try` and `catch` block.

Comment: @trashgod what is a mcve?

Comment: @MattMurch: Click the link for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need a try/catch statement around your writer.

Such as:

```
private void ExportGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("Inventory.txt");
        for (String str : Inventory) {
            writer.write(str);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception, rethrow or log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ignore){

        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

FileWriter extends OutputStreamWriter which is where it gets its `write` method from.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write(char[], int, int)

According to the docs write throws an `IOException`.

In Java you have to either wrap the code that throws an exception in a try catch block. Or throw the exception.

```
private void ExportGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    FileWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("Inventory.txt");
        for (String str : Inventory) {
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         //Do something here to handle the error. Maybe publish a notification to the user that their file didn't write.
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ignore){}
    }
}
```

Note that the `FileWriter` constructor you're using can also throw an `IOException` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String)) as well as the `close` method. So you need to include all of those statements within the try block.

The finally block is there to close your handle to the file if at all possible. The try-with-resource gets rid of the need to do that though. So I recommend using it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I tried what you suggested, NetBeans is now reporting that it can not find 'class IOException'. Also the final part of the generated code 'public static void main(String args[]) {' is now reported to be an 'illegal start of expreshion'.

Comment: Make sure to add the right import statement: import java.io.IOException;